# How to work with large files in php

Tags: php, file

I need to work with large files in php using fopen,fwrite,fseek and fread on large files (4GB<), however, php seams to have troubles with anything larger than 2GB, i know about php x64, but somehow it does not work, or i just cant configure it correctly. I need a reliable solution. problem is, I am not running my scripts in a server environment, but as standalone command line apps.

Answer (score 2):

php is likely having trouble because your loading the whole file in to memory, If you buffer the file and loop though it shouldnt have an issue.

if your running it as a command line app, there are unix core tools which are likely better suited for the job

Answer (score 0):

If I remember a similar problem I had, you have to use fgets because this function reads one line at a time and it doesn't load the whole file in memory.

Comment: it has nothing to do with loading the whole file into memory, i use fseek and fread to read from byte position x to y... i beilieve the problem to be the 2GB file limit of php x32 and number limitations of float values... but how can i overcome them?

Comment: Ok. Well it seems that the problem is linked to filesize() : http://lenss.nl/2011/08/php5-filesize-limit-on-32-bit-system/ . Even if you don't use it, fread, fseek are using it. There is some patch for 32 bit version of php, but I think it is easier to install a 64 bit version of php.

Comment: You are running your script on which OS ? Because it is not so difficult to install a 64 bit version of php. And I think it is the solution.

Comment: Good, i am runing windows 8 x64... how can i install php x64?

Comment: Here if you want to test php 5.5QA : http://windows.php.net/qa/ or here http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-5-and-php-5-3-15-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ . You just have to unzip.